# Single line prevents entire script from working correctly

Tags: php

I have a huge php file that does various things based on URL variables.

Everything works fine on my WAMP server, but when I put it on my real server the file stops working.

I have narrowed it down to one line of code. If I comment that line out, everything works just fine.

here is that line:

```
$ext = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']))['extension'];
```

The PHP version on my WAMP server is `5.4.12` and on my server it is `5.2.17`

I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Thanks up front, for any answers.

Comment: Your title is inaccurate - you seem to be able to post messages :-)

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Define "stops working."  Is there an error?  If that line is failing, it must be failing in some noticeable way.

Comment: For debugging purposes why not write the variables to a file for examination

Comment: @David No error. With that line in the code, the browser displays and empty page.

Comment: array dereferencing was introduced in PHP 5.4, so you'll have a syntax error on PHP 5.2.... check the server logs

Comment: Why are you developing against a different version of PHP to the server where you're deploying the code for production?

Comment: @DinoPrašo empty page doesn't mean "no error", means you _do_ have errors but not showing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your code like that.

```
$ext = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));
$ext = $ext['extension'];
```

as the php on your real server is lower than in your wamp, and not support megration betwhen function and array, check if this can fix your problem.

Comment: What is `megration betwhen function and array` ?

Comment: it's my own definition of using a function that return array and instated of add result to a variable and getting the array field from the variable, you use function and get result in the same line, like above example.

Answer (score 3):

You're using function array dereferencing, which was only added in PHP5.4

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you try to access the item extension directly from pathinfo(). This will work better, because it's supported in versions before PHP 5.4-

```
$tmpExt = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));
$ext = $tmpExt['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use this instead?

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```